# Simulate fixed axis for iphone accelerometer

Tags: ios, accelerometer, physics, gyroscope

I'm making an app in which the user can move their devices left, right, up, and down in order to view an image. The way I'm doing this is by reading in the accelerometer data to calculate how far in each direction the user moved the device. The issue is that these readings are heavily influenced by the tilt of the device, because the axis change slightly with every tiny tilt. I know the gyroscope measures the rotational accelerations, so is there a way I could use those readings to take tilt out of the picture and fix the axis so they are the same at whatever angle the user holds the device? I realize this is a very eloborate problem, so if you don't understand something feel free to ask

Comment: Mathematically, yes, that is feasible. Which part is giving you trouble? Do you know how to integrate linear accelerations to find the location of the device? Do you know how to integrate rotational accelerations to find its orientation? Given orientation as a function of time, do you know how to transform a linear acceleration vector from the device's body coordinates to the non-rotating coordinate system? Have you done this kind of math/programming before? How do you represent a rotation mathematically?

Comment: I don't individually know how to do a few of those, but I'm working with a team and the person who is working the math understands how to do all of that

Comment: So what part is giving you trouble? And how do you represent a rotation?

Comment: I think I may have figured it out based off of your questions actually. Thanks so much haha